# How to run/connect to Entrypoint process via socket/port (executable)

Tags: docker, server, dockerfile, wkhtmltopdf

TL;DR
"Reading/writing to stdin/stdout of Entrypoint executable process on running container (ex. Docker, podman) via socket/http"

My question is in regards to executable containers and how to spin/wrap them up as servers, and connect to them remotely (socket/curl/http).

I have an executable container that is not a server, just a standalone executable **ENTRYPOINT** command. ([Example: wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/Surnet/docker-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/archive/alpine-wkhtmltopdf/Dockerfile_3.12.4-0.12.6-full)). I would love to use an image like that as a container, but not make it a part of my own container/Dockerfile (i.e. not to modify/maintain it).

As I understand if I run this image as a container, it will immediately die as there is no input/ on this process and it does not act as a server/listening for connections.

A lot of tutorials state that you can run containers via `docker run ...` command.

If I am on `Windows` inside `WSL2` distro I am not necessarily going to have `docker` installed locally. But I believe that we can connect to other containers that are on the same network (default `bridge` network).

But how would one spin-up/expose executable container as a server and connect to it's `stdin`/`stdout`?

I want for container to listen on port (direct to executable `stdin`), process the request with said executable, and obtain the results from `stdout`/curl.

What I think can work:

[Spinning process as a server (Golang example)](https://github.com/djmattyg007/wkhtmltopdf-server/blob/master/wkhtmltox-server.go)

Do I need to wrap every executable that I want ***to expose BUT not make it as a part of my own Dockerfile*** or is there a common pattern/tool I can use for such a scenario.

P.S. `wkhtmltopdf` executable example I gave also comes with [python](https://github.com/Surnet/docker-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/archive/alpine-python-wkhtmltopdf/Dockerfile_3.9.9-0.12.6-full) and [node](https://github.com/Surnet/docker-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/archive/alpine-node-wkhtmltopdf/Dockerfile_16.13.1-0.12.6-full) included. (I am thinking about some sort of one-liner solution akin to `docker run --rm -v ... X ... python -m SimpleHTTPServer ...` )

Answer (score 0):

This answer just describes the situation on Linux.

I haven't tested this but I think you could combine systemd socket activation

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:9999
Accept=yes
```

(see example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551000/systemd-socket-activation-stdin)

with **netcat** (see example
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332163/netcat-send-text-to-echo-service-read-reply-then-exit)

Use the `-i` flag, i.e., `podman run -i ...` or `docker run -i` to pass stdin in to the container.